# Unclear Transition and Former Manager Not Respecting Role

Tags: work-environment

I currently lead a team of four Software Engineers. This team takes inputs from other teams and makes software. My former manager was picked to help another team. I have been leading my team for some time and my former manager always intended for me to take over when they left someday. That day came surprisingly two weeks ago when I found out that my former manager was pulled to permanently help another team falling behind. Great for me except now I was given more work with the same pay, organizational charts have not been updated showing me as the new ‘lead’, and there was no announcement of me leaving. So people still try to contact my former manager and this person offers opinions on things that are no longer their responsibility. Additionally, I have not been invited to leadership level meetings that my former manager went to and feel like I am being given a role with zero mandate nor respect. The fact that my former manager insists on trying to be involved to boss me around when this person is not in the role anymore is also troublesome. When this manager went to the other team, it’s like things have flipped. This manager now has gone native and the same rules that the manager used to apply to that team, no longer apply that the manager is there.

How do I de conflict with this person who now has a new found outlook and instead of working to fix the team is now seemingly working against me? How do get around these feelings of being in limbo? There’s no guarantee for a promotion even though I am doing the job this manager did but at a lower level.

Comment: If you have not been formally promoted, is it possible that the person you are calling the former manager is either in their own mind or even officially still the manager of your team, even if you have a larger day to day role while they are busy elsewhere?  Can you share what in what precise way you were told that your role is expanded?

Comment: @Chris Stratton: No I had a meeting with former managers former boss and now my boss and he said I am taking the team

Comment: Given that it doesn't seem like the organization as a whole is considering you a manager, perhaps you need to schedule a followup meeting and ask if you are going to be designated as the person in that role, or if they are merely wanting you to fill in temporarily as more of a leader among peers.  Consider too that even if you are formally promoted people are likely to still seek the former manager's opinion and (perceived) value of their experience.

Comment: What does your current manager say

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have two problems here.

First, the person you're replacing isn't letting go of his old job. You can address this by speaking to him in private. Ask him to help you succeed in your new role by sending people to you with questions.  "That's a question for Brian now" is all he has to say. You can ask him questions if you need help. But questions from others *must* come to you.

You can't succeed unless he supports you by letting you actually do the job he used to do. By doing part of it for you he's messing you up and messing himself up.

Notice that letting go of old jobs is *very hard* for some people. You'll need to remind him a few times.

Second, your boss in your new job hasn't really announced your new job and updated the org chart. You might ask that person for advice like this: "in your experience what does it take for somebody like me to do  the best possible work in a new job?" That should open up a constructive conversation about the steps in your transition.

Be patient for weeks, but not for months, with a slow transition.

Answer (score 1):

> So people still try to contact my former manager and this person offers opinions on things that are no longer their responsibility

I wouldn't assume malice here, it's possible he's still trying to be helpful. I'd drop him a line and just say something akin to:

> Hi Bob, if any correspondance for your old team lands your way, would you mind either just forwarding it on and/or let them know that I'm now the TL? Some people still don't seem to be aware and I think it's causing confusion. Thanks!

Look at his reply, and take things from there.

> Additionally, I have not been invited to leadership level meetings that my former manager went to

You don't have to spend your time going to meetings? Fantastic! Wish I had that problem.

> organizational charts have not been updated showing me as the new ‘lead’

Contact HR, explain that there's a bit of confusion because org chart is out of date, and ask if they can update the org chart ASAP.

In general, I'd advise knuckling down and doing what you've been appointed to do as well as you can - lead your tell well, make sure they're well equipped and resourced, deadlines are met, work is well managed, and any problems are dealt with swiftly and professionally. It may take you some time as a new TL to gain the reputation of your former manager, but that's natural. If you keep doing what you're doing, and doing it well, then that will likely get noticed. If you make too much of a noise about how you're not respected, and you want to go to meetings so you're in the loop, that likely won't reflect as well on you longer term.